# objective-C dragging images into NSTextView subclass

Tags: macos, cocoa

I’ve created a Cocoa-made text editing application that mimicks TextEdit with some
other features added. I use a subclass of NSTextView. My problem is,  I can’t drag images (jpeg for example), into my text window, as I would do in TextEdit.

I tried the following : The -init method of my subclass is as follows :

```
- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {

    // Add your subclass-specific initialization here.
    // If an error occurs here, send a [self release] message and return nil.
    [self setImportsGraphics:YES];

}

return self;
}
```

But the problem stays the same ... Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is your textfield specified to be rich text using `setRichText:`?

Comment: @SimonM  The NSTextField class is certainly used in my app because it interacts with many other classes, but I never use it directly in my code. Also, adding [self setRichText:YES] to [self setImportsGraphics:YES] in the code above does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that that init function is being called?

Perhaps you should override and add the "setImportGraphics" line to the initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame function instead.